# Acceptance tests using Cucumber/Webdriver never complete

Tags: cucumber, webdriver, gherkin, cucumber-jvm

We're using Gherkin, Cucumber-jvm and Webdriver to run acceptance tests against a standard Java/Spring webapp. The issue is that, when running the tests using a Maven job, the tests completely successfully but the job does not complete. Only on closing of the Firefox window does the job complete.

We have a workaround of closing the browser explicitly after each feature, but this will quickly become unsustainable due to time lag.

The tech stack is as follows:

Cucumber-JVM 1.0.4

Selenium 2.12.0

Firefox 8.0

The app runs in JBoss EAP 5.1 on a Windows 7 machine.

When we used the JRuby version of Cucumber, this behaviour did not appear with the above selenium/firefox combination, although it did when we used higher versions of either.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, and does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you mean by "quickly become unsustainable due to time lag." ?

Comment: Our test suite (2000+ steps) was taking up to 40 mins to run, using a single Firefox browser instance. Adding the overhead of closing/re-opening the browser for each feature file (with a tag) or scenario was adding more time to this, bringing it to an unsustainable level in a fast-changing codebase.

Comment: run them in parallel [https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/86](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/86).

Comment: Very interesting - I really appreciate your help on this, thank you. Do you know if this only works when using Surefire and JUnit? We're sticking with the CLI approach for the moment, as we need to allow the user specify on the command line which tags to run.

Comment: "which tags to run"? Neither Cucumber nor Selenium have notion of tag . Who is working under the role "User"?

Comment: We have each scenario annotated with a tag - Common with an @ beforehand, or @Stub, for instance. We need to be able to run any combination of tests through the command line, specified by the --tags argument to cucumber.cli.Main

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10744/discussion-between-artem-oboturov-and-truedub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you close your WebDriver?

```
@cucumber.annotation.After
public void afterScenarioRun() {
    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes we do, but it's this I'm trying to avoid - the overhead of having to close & then reopen a browser window is impacting on the run times of the suite, and will only get worse. I'm hoping there's another solution - something like an @EndSuite option.

Comment: Look at hooks : [https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks)

Comment: My suggestion about Hooks wouldn't work because for cucumber-jre they essentially the same as After and Before :  cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend#addHook

Comment: You could implement cucumber.runtime.Backend#buildWorld and cucumber.runtime.Backend#disposeWorld to create and instance of WebDriver and to close it. And put implementation of Backend class to cucumbers's classpath. See source of cucumber.runtime.Runtime#loadBackends : subclass Backend and put your subclass to cucumber.runtime.YouBackendImplementation. Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Looking at the interface Backend, it says that disposeWorld is invoked at the end of a scenario, not of a completed test run.

Answer (score 1):

I use Cucumber and Selenium in a spring environment (with cucumber-spring). When the WebDriver is managed by Spring, you can add `destroy="close"` to the bean defintion:

```
<bean id="webDriver" class="org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver" destroy-method="close"/>
```

This closes the browser after all tests have finished.